# Import JSON documents in MySQL in Bluemix Dedicated platform

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I have a MySQL DB deployed in Bluemix(ibm-cloud) dedicated.
Installed MySQL shell 8.0.15 for Windows and tried to import a JSON file and got the error message:

> ERROR: Util.importJson: An X Protocol session is required for JSON
>   import.

Tried to create a connection using X protocol and got the following error message:

> MySQL [xx-xx-north-1-xxxxx.xx.xxlayer.com ssl/dummy] JS>
>   shell.connect('mysqlx://admin@xx-xx-north-1-xxxxx.xx.xxlayer.com:xxxxx'
>   ) Creating an X protocol session to
>   'admin@xx-xx-north-1-xxxxx.xx.xxlayer.com:xxxxx' Requested session
>   assumes MySQL X Protocol but
>   'xx-xx-north-1-xxxxx.xx.xxlayer.com:xxxxx' seems to speak the classic
>   MySQL protoc ol (Unexpected response received from server ) (MySQL
>   Error 2027)

Does that mean that Bluemix(ibm-cloud) Dedicated does not support X protocol.  If that is the case, what is the alternate to import JSON documents.

Thnx.